openldap show all operational attributes
Is there a way to deliver all operational attributes (e.g. memberOf) of a ldapsearch? I know if i add a '+' to ldapsearch i will get all attributes (incl. operational ones). In the acl there is an entry:
olcAccess: to * by * read

So the attribute can be read. All search queries with memberOf are working, but the result data sets do not have this operational attribute listed.

"All search queries with memberOf are working, but the result data sets do not have this operational attribute listed" - I might need more coffee, but what is the issue at hand? Is it that after a DN has been added to a GroupOfNames, and you query that DN, there is no memberOf that shows the ("reverse") mapping and that group membership?  That might be because memberOf is an OpenLDAP overlay that usually needs activating before the synthetic attribute memberOf gets populated. https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Reverse%20Group%20Membership%20Maintenance

No, my problem is that i have an application that queries the ldap und searches the result for the memberOf attribute. Each query - on ldap server or from the app - get the exact result, but the app shows an error that the memberOf function is not available. That is why the app searches the result for the memberOf attribute but did not get it. So my question is if it is possible (maybe with workaround) to return the memberOf attribute every query.
